# Basic math operations with HUGE numbers

Tags: c, math, bignum

By huge numbers, I mean if you took a gigabyte (instead of 4/8 bytes etc.) and tried to add/subtract/multiply/divide it by some other arbitrarily large (or small) number.

Adding and subtracting are rather easy (one k/m/byte at a time):

```
out_byteN = a_byteN + b_byteN + overflowBit
```

For every byte, thus I can add/subtract as I read the number from the disk and not risk running out of RAM.

For multiplying/dividing, simply do the above in a loop.

But what about taking the nth root of a HUGE number?

Comment: Numerical operations have big-O runtime and memory complexity just like "real" programs do. We programmers just tend to ignore or minimize the variability of their expense by always using the same operand size. Wikipedia's coverage of math operations typically does include such analysis, though. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root#Computing_principal_roots

Comment: FYI, there are *much* faster ways of doing multiplication on large numbers.

Comment: @MAK: actually the alternatives don't get much faster until the numbers get **very** large.

Comment: By the way, nice question, but I wouldn't consider square root a "basic" operation.

Comment: @R..: not *very* large though. To perform x*y, the OP is adding x to itself y times. Even if x and y are as small as 100 or 1000, the basic multiplication algorithm we learn in primary school is much faster.

Comment: You shouldn't do multiplication naively for numbers of this size, there are much better algorithms. http://cosec.bit.uni-bonn.de/science/mca/mca-gallery/mca-fastmult/

Comment: Oh, I misread and assumed OP was using grade-school multiplication. You're right then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Same as any other number: [Newton iteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

Answer (score 8):

Are you asking for something like "The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library" (at http://gmplib.org/)?

Comment: You mean the GNU crash-your-program-with-`abort()`-when-passed-huge-numbers Multiprecision Arithmetic Library?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways: Bisection, Newtons, Householder's method.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [Arbitrary-precision Arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) library.   [BigDigits](http://www.di-mgt.com.au/bigdigits.html) is a good one.